# Accidently deleted /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White

Tags: icons, icon-themes

Now I lost the dmz cursor and I always get the following error when `sudo apt upgrade`

```
Setting up dmz-cursor-theme (0.4.5ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package dmz-cursor-theme (--configure):
 installed dmz-cursor-theme package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dmz-cursor-theme
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I recover this file? I already tried with `sudo apt install --reinstall dmz-cursor-theme` but I only get the error

```
E: Internal Error, No file name for dmz-cursor-theme:amd64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually recreate the file path with:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/
```

and then run reinstallation:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dmz-cursor-theme
```

or if it continue to fail - install its package from cache directly:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/dmz-cursor-theme*.deb
```

Comment: The last line worked. I just had to download dmz-cursor-theme deb from https://pkgs.org/